# Postgres repeatable read - how I can delete existing rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

First of all I use ORM for generating queries.
My models look like this:

```
Category hasMany CategoryTranslation
CategoryTranslation.slug is UNIQUE
```

What I want is to update category which involves 3 steps:

1. update Category attributes
2. delete all CategoryTranslation that belongs to this category
3. create new CategoryTranslations

Here is SQL generated:

```
Executing (777e5f34-1078-4b1b-9eb6-09e117bbf751): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (777e5f34-1078-4b1b-9eb6-09e117bbf751): SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
Executing (777e5f34-1078-4b1b-9eb6-09e117bbf751): SET autocommit = 1;
Executing (777e5f34-1078-4b1b-9eb6-09e117bbf751): UPDATE "Categories" SET "id"=20 WHERE "id"=20 RETURNING *
Executing (777e5f34-1078-4b1b-9eb6-09e117bbf751): DELETE FROM "CategoryTranslations" WHERE "id" IN (SELECT "id" FROM "CategoryTranslations" WHERE "CategoryId"=20)
Executing (777e5f34-1078-4b1b-9eb6-09e117bbf751): INSERT INTO "CategoryTranslations" ("name","slug","description","seoTitle","seoDescription","language","CategoryId","id","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ('123f','sdcfsdf','sdf','sdf','sdf','en-us',NULL,DEFAULT,'2014-05-22 11:35:18.635 +00:00','2014-05-22 11:35:18.635 +00:00') RETURNING *;
Executing (777e5f34-1078-4b1b-9eb6-09e117bbf751): ROLLBACK;
```

The problem is that no CatgoryTranslations are deleted in this query and inserting new one violates UNIQUE key on slug column.
Is it possible to delete existing (pre-transaction-existing) rows in transaction (repeatable read)? Or I should use other transaction isolation level?

My goal is to accomplish 3 steps I mentioned in "all or nothing" mode...

Comment: Sounds like you actually want `read committed` not `repeatable read`. Also: switching to autocommit mode while inside a transaction sounds rather dubious as well.

Comment: In your own transaction you can of course see all your own writes. The isolation level dictates what you see from others and what others see from you. The problem is not with isolation levels. Why do you even suspect that? Sounds like your delete statement is wrong so that it matches nothing.

Comment: @usr: the isolation level *does* dictate what you see. With `repeatable read` you don't see any changes that happened *after* your transaction started - regardless whether they were committed or not. `read committed` on the other side will make committed changes visible inside your transaction even if the changes happened after your transaction started.

Comment: He seems to be using one transaction only. He suspect that he cannot see his own writes in that transaction, which is not the case.

Comment: Sorry guys it seems that there was a bug in my app that somehow generated CategoryTranslation with CategoryId = null...